# Python Print objects in class

Tags: python, class

So I have list of objects in class and I need to print all different songs from one singer.
So far I have this code and I am not sure is it correct

Also I need to use recursion method

```
def allmusic(listofobjects, name):
    nameandsurname=self.name
    if(listofobjects.name==nameandsurname):
        print(listofobjects.music)
        return(listofobjects(music[1:]))
    else:
        return(listofobjects(name[1:]))
```

Also I need to print  number of singers in that class and code I have is

```
def allmusic(listofobjects):
    numberofsingers=0
    for s in listofobjects:
       numberofsingers+=1
       return(listofobjects()[1:])
    print(numberofsingers)
```

Comment: What is `self` supposed to refer to in the first attempt? What do the elements of the input list look like?

Comment: So i have init method 

class Music
def __init__(self,music,year,howlong,typeofmusic,nameofsinger):
  self.music=music
  self.year=year
  self.howlong=howlong
  self.typeofmusic=typeofmusic
  self.nameofsinger=nameofsinger

Comment: You need to add self in every function argument inside the class.

Comment: So i think when you create def method its already in class and you dont need to type everytime self

Comment: Refer to this link. https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/self-in-python-class/amp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want. It recursively prints the all songs of a specific singer provided in the arguments. Here listOfMusic is the list of Music objects.

```
def PrintSinger(self, listOfMusic, name):
        if(listOfMusic[0].nameOfSinger == name):
            print(listOfMusic[0].music)
        if(len(listOfMusic) ==  1):
            return
        else:
            return self.PrintSinger(listOfMusic[1:], name)
```